# Disable Open New Window (Ctrl+N) shortcut Firefox 4

Tags: firefox

I am trying to restrict few users (who are not very computer literate) in my organisation, to restrict them to one Firefox window. So I would like to disable "Open New Window" feature. Is there an option in the `about:config`? I tried to hunting for it, but could not find any.

Comment: This is likely better asked against [Firefox support](http://support.mozilla.com/). I know in earlier versions of Firefox the shortcut keys were locked in and not editable by users. I assume that restriction still exists.

Comment: Thanks Marco. I will try that as well. askubuntu is awesome, so I tried first here ;)

Answer (score 2):

Would a "Kiosk" type mode suit you needs?
[R-kiosk](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/r-kiosk/):

> defaults to full screen, disables all menus, toolbars, key commands
>   and right button menus. Alt+Home still takes you home.

Might be overkill, but it would certainly eliminate the option to open new windows...hmm,only shows compatibiliy up to 3.6.x, but it might still work or there may be a v 4|5 similar addon.

Comment: sometimes overkill is good!

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Switch Window Mode](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/switch-window-mode/) add-on for firefox

Comment: This does not help. This changes any new pop up which comes as new window to new tab. What I am looking is to get application to work only in one window and no option to spawn a new window

Comment: How about the Single Window Mode in Tab Mix Plus? It only allows one window to be open at a time.  It doesn't remove the option but it will just open another tab instead of a new window.